# How to use jquery trigger anchor's default click event?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have an anchor in my page like :`<a href="#header" id="anchor">turn to header</a>`  then I also set a button in my page `<input type="button" value="triger anchor">`  .What I want to do is that ,when I click the button ,it will triger the anchor's default click event ,as the page  turn to "header".So I write  `$("input").click(function(){$("#anchor").trigger("click");});`  But it seems doesn't work .So how can I achieve that?Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762703/re-firing-a-click-event-on-a-link-with-jquery/1763231#1763231).

Instead of trying to trigger the `click` event, try setting the `window.location` property:

```
window.location = '#header';
```

Or perhaps:

```
$("input").click(function() {
  window.location = $('#anchor').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Note that this will not send the referer for IE6, IE7 and I think IE8.

Answer (score 5):

Try This, working for Me !!

```
$("#anchor").get(0).click();
```

This will call default click of the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can Also use to trigger click/any events

```
$('#bycategory').click(function(){
  alert('triggered');
});
$('#bycategory').triggerHandler("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have a way to trigger the native DOM event directly.

To do that, you can use the plain old standard DOM methods:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
$('#anchor').get(0).dispatchEvent(evt);
```

For support of IE8 or earlier, you need to use the IE-specific event methods `createEventObject` and `fireEvent`.

Answer (score -1):

You have a spelling error. Please use:

```
{$("#anchor").trigger("click");});
```

Comment: ……I'm sorry ,it just a write mistake .In my project it is"trigger",and doesn;t work……

Comment: ok, try to add $("#anchor").bind('click', function(){alert('click')}); it is help you to check that event is happend

Comment: also add attrib. id for button and use it in your jQuery's query

Comment: all this help you to find the reason of problem.