# jQuery auto click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Ok, so I searched all over with no answer.
Can someone explain why

does not work with `.trigger('click')`

```
<a id="openNew" href="http://www.example.org">Click me</a>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#openNew').addClass("external").attr({ target: "_blank", href: 'http://www.google.com' }).trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

and it does not work with `.click()`

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#openNew').addClass("external").attr({ target: "_blank", href: 'http://www.google.com' }).click();
    });
</script>
```

Does not click the link whatever I do. It only works if I click it. How can I make it auto click?
Working on this for about 1 hour and is driving me crazy, I know I'm must be doing something stupid.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2KuF/) for your convenience.

I wouldn't mind any other solution in plain JavaScript.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  You're asking how to simulate a click of an anchor tag using jquery click/trigger. [Here is a previous post with your answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482074/how-to-use-jquery-trigger-anchors-default-click-event)

Comment: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2KuF/9/) Showing that the click even is being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulating a user physically clicking the link is not possible. Since you are using target='_blank' I presume you want a new window? So you'll need to use window.open. Which popup blockers wont like.

Answer (score 1):

Use `elem[0].click();` instead of `elem.click();` since you want to call the native click function and not just trigger the click event.

By the way: Popup blockers will prevent this from actually opening a new window (luckily).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's clicked, but not opened link.. check out here http://jsfiddle.net/H2KuF/5/

Probably you need to open new browser window with this link from JS.

here is samples I found:

```
function open2(url, opt){
  if (opt == 0) // current window
    window.location = url;
  else if (opt == 1) // new window
    window.open(url);
  else if (opt == 2) // background window
    {window.open(url); self.focus();}
}
```

Comment: Basically this answer is correct.  The click event is being triggered it just isn't doing what you think it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Karl swedberg states [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) (One of the comments)

> Using .trigger('click') will not trigger the native click event.

Doing the following will work:

```
<a id="openNew" href="http://www.example.org">Click me</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#openNew').addClass("external").attr({ target: "_blank", href: 'http://www.google.com' })[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/H2KuF/12/)