# Trigger anchor link click when checkbox is checked in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [re-firing a click event on a link with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762703/re-firing-a-click-event-on-a-link-with-jquery)

Is is possible to tigger an anchor link being clicked when checking a checkbox?? Below is my html and jQuery

Html:

```
<div id="filter-1" class="filter tags">
 <ul>
  <li class="grey">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <a title="" href="/collections/mens/grey">Grey</a>
  </li>

 <li class="all">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <a title="" href="/collections/mens">All color</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var item=$(this);    
   if(item.is(":checked"))
    {
     item.siblings('a').trigger('click');
    }    
 });
```

Comment: So do you want JS to do the default click action (i.e. navigating the link) when checkbox click?

Comment: Er, isn't that a stupid thing to want to do?

Comment: What does it do now? Does it throw an error of any kind?

Comment: What's the freaking purpose of the `checkbox` then?

Comment: You realise its easier to click am actual link, rather than a (often smaller) checkbox element?

Comment: The purposes is to be able to click both. If you have a better solution feel free to post it.

Comment: And the client wants to have a checkbox and a link. Not sure why

Comment: possible duplicate of [re-firing a click event on a link with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762703/re-firing-a-click-event-on-a-link-with-jquery) and [How to use jquery trigger anchor's default click event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482074/how-to-use-jquery-trigger-anchors-default-click-event)(that actually seems to be the better one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var item=$(this);    
   if(item.is(":checked"))
    {
      location.href = item.siblings('a').attr('href');
    }    
 });
```

Comment: whatever you wanna achieve with that, I think this should help... :)

Comment: if he's trying to actually trigger the `click` event in order to run code bound to that event, then this will not work however.

Comment: This actually got me curious, and I did some [jsfiddlin'](http://jsfiddle.net/yY4Nc/) and searchin'..  It looks like, technically, OP's code probably *was* "triggering" the click event, but this is not equivalent to actually "clicking" the link.  See [this answer to another SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12166799/363701).