# Trigger a click event on an inner element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

A row in a table where each first cell contains a link needs to be clicked and open a url.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="fancybox" href="detail.aspx?CID=67525">LT5C260A436C41</a></td> 
    <td>more data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="fancybox" href="detail.aspx?CID=17522">LA5C260D436C41</a></td> 
    <td>more data</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

The complete row should be clickable instead of only the link top open the detail page in a [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), ie in the page itself.

So I *tried* to do something like this:

```
$("table tr").bind('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("a").trigger('click');
});
```

But it seems that the event is bubbling recursivly resulting in a:

> Uncaught RangeError: **Maximum call stack size exceeded**

**How can I trigger the click on the full row instead of only the link in a proper way avoiding the stackoverflow?**

UPDATE: I really appreciate the answers below, but **my question is about triggering the event, NOT executing the behaviour inside that event.** Workarounds could be nice, but not in this case.

Comment: Put it in a jsfiddle so we can help you more appropriately

Comment: I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/F5aMb/ I added the onclick to see if it was simulating the click and it is registering a click to the `a` but it's not following the link.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: See my update.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne, I gave the explanation of recursion and a tiny reusable workaround.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This worked well:

```
$("table tr").click(function(e) {
    var $link = $(this).find("a");

    if (e.target === $link[0]) return false;

    $link.trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT:**

*Why most solutions don't work* — they fail, because when the link was clicked, the immediate handler attached runs. The event then **bubbles** to see if a handler was attached to a table cell, row, etc.

When you suggest triggering a click you cause the recursion: the link was clicked → fancybox → bubbles → aha! table row → trigger the link click → the link was clicked…

When you suggest to stop propagation, please note that event stops bubbling to parent elements, so a `click` handler attached to `body` will not be executed.

*Why the code above works* — we check if the event bubbled from a link. If true, we simply return and stop **further** propagation.

---

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5aMb/28/

Answer (score 10):

try

```
$('table tr').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(href) {
       window.location = href;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've spent far too long trying to streamline something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

<s>Try this:</s>

```
$("table tr a").bind('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.open($(this).attr('href'));
     return false;
});

$("table tr").bind('click', function(e) {
     $(this).find("a").trigger('click');
 });
```

I found what went wrong.

In your code,

```
$("table tr").bind('click',function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
$(this).find("a").trigger('click');//This line again triggers a click event binded on the tr ELEMENT which contains the 'a' ELEMENT. So it goes into a infinite loop.
});
```

### Update:

[This will do.](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/F5aMb/3/)

```
$("table tr").bind('click', function(e) {
   window.location.href = $(this).find("a.fancybox").attr('href');
});
```

`$(this).find("a").trigger('click');` is actually not triggering the default 
    anchor tag behavior. It just tries to trigger a click event if a click event 
    is already bound to that element explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that I misunderstood your question, but doesn't this do what you need:

```
$("table tr").click(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (! $(e.target).is('a')) {
        $(this).find("a").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For the funny purpose of this exercise, here is a pure js solution, i.e., w/o using jQ lib).

Available here for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/Sr5Vy/3/

```
<table>
  <tr id="node_1">
    <td><a class="fancybox" href="detail.aspx?CID=67525">LT5C260A436C41</a></td>
    <td>more data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="node_2">
    <td><a class="fancybox" href="detail.aspx?CID=17522">LA5C260D436C41</a></td>
    <td>more data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
function AddEvent(id, evt_type, ma_fonction, phase) {
  var oElt = document.getElementById(id);
  if( oElt.addEventListener ) {
      oElt.addEventListener(evt_type, ma_fonction, phase);
  } else if( oElt.attachEvent ) {
      oElt.attachEvent('on'+evt_type, ma_fonction);
  }

    // Debug
    // alert('a \'' + evt_type + '\' event has been attached on ' + id );

    return false;
}

function getElementsByRegExpOnId(search_reg, search_element, search_tagName) {
    search_element = (search_element === undefined) ? document : search_element;
    search_tagName= (search_tagName === undefined) ? '*' : search_tagName;
    var id_return = new Array;
    for(var i = 0, i_length = search_element.getElementsByTagName(search_tagName).length; i < i_length; i++) {
        if (search_element.getElementsByTagName(search_tagName).item(i).id &&
        search_element.getElementsByTagName(search_tagName).item(i).id.match(search_reg)) {
            id_return.push(search_element.getElementsByTagName(search_tagName).item(i).id) ;
        }
    }
    return id_return; // array
}

function FollowSpecialLinks(event) {

    // Debug
    // alert('event was successfully attached');

    // Prevent propagation
    event.preventDefault();

    // Identify targetted node (eg one of the children of <tr>)
    var targetted_elt = ShowEventSource(event);
    //alert('Event\'s target : ' + targetted_elt);

    // Extract the targetted url
    if (targetted_elt == "A") {
        var current_link = GetEventSource(event).href;

    } else {
        var current_tr = GetEventSource(event).parentNode;
        var child_links = current_tr.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var current_link = child_links[0].href;
    }



   // Now open the link
    if(current_link) {
        // Debug  
        alert('will now open href : ' + current_link);
       window.location = current_link;
    }


}

function GetEventSource(event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    var myelt = e.target || e.srcElement;
    return myelt;
}

function ShowEventSource(event) {
    var elmt;
    var event = event || window.event;            // W3C ou MS
    var la_cible = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (la_cible.nodeType == 3)            // Vs bug Safari
        elmt = la_cible.parentNode;                        
    else
        elmt = la_cible.tagName;
   return elmt;
}

// Get all document <tr> id's and attach the "click" events to them
  my_rows = new Array();
  my_rows = getElementsByRegExpOnId(/^node_.+/, document , 'tr') ;
    if (my_rows) {
        for (i=0; i< my_rows.length; i++ ) {
            var every_row = document.getElementById( my_rows[i] ) ;
            AddEvent(every_row.id, 'click', FollowSpecialLinks, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between `ShowEventSource`   and `GetEventSource`?  `ShowEventSource` can return either a node or a tagName, which sounds really wrong. But you only use it as returning a tagName. Overall, pretty messy, hard to understand, not very didactical and not addressing the real question. I'm sure you learned something from this, but I don't see it as useful to others reading this question

Comment: ShowEventSource handles the Safari bugs, so it's not wong. The overall does the trick so it answers the question somehow but w/o Jquery, which does not help really understanding DOM events.

Comment: `ShowEventSource` *is* wrong in the sense that its name doesn't indicate what it does, considering `GetEventSource` already does that (but not well enough, so another function similarly named is used to address its deficiencies)

Comment: Clear. ShowEventSource is not really used, as it's only for explanation or pedagogic purposes so yes, for sure, it duplicates somehow GetEventSource. I thought it was obvious. End of the story.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".fancybox").parent('td').parent('tr').bind('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("a").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: That will create the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried stopping immediate propagation when you click the link?This way you should stop the recursion

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert('hi');
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3VMGn/2/

Comment: Yeah, it does register a click on the link but **doesn't** follow the link, that's the problem he's having

Answer (score 2):

In order to compensate for the bubbling, you need to detect the target of the event and not click on the link more than once.
Also, jQuery's "trigger" function won't work for plain links, so you need a specialized click function.

you can try it out at: http://jsfiddle.net/F5aMb/27/

```
$("table tr").each(function(i, tr){
    $(tr).bind('click',function(e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if( !target.is("a") ) {
            clickLink($(this).find("a")[0]);
        }
    })
});


function clickLink(element) {
   if (document.createEvent) {
       // dispatch for firefox + others
       var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
       evt.initEvent("click", true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
       return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
   } else {
       //IE
       element.click()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by giving each link a unique ID and then using jQuery to set the click event of that unique ID to redirect the window to the appropriate page.

Here is my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/F5aMb/2/

And here is the code:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
    // do whatever I want here, then redirect
    window.location.href = "detail.aspx?CID=67525";
});
$('#link2').click(function(){
    // do whatever I want here, then redirect
    window.location.href = "detail.aspx?CID=17522";
});

$("table tr").click(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).find("a").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with following code. I tested it on you jsfilddle seems working.

```
$("table tr").click(function(e) {

   // check if click event is on link or not.
   // if it's link, don't stop further propagation
   // so, link href will be followed.

  if($(e.target).attr('class')=='fancybox'){
    alert('you clicked link, so what next ?.');

  // else if click is happened somewhere else than link, 
  // stop the propagation, so that it won't go in recursion.

  }else{
    alert('no link clicked, :( ');
    alert('now clicking link prgrammatically');
    $(this).find('a').click(); 
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Let me know, if you want to achieve something else than this.

Answer (score 1):

I think `.click()` or `.trigger("click")` only fires the event handlers for `onclick`.

See a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/sethi/bEDPp/4/
. Manually clicking on the link shows 2 alerts while firing the event through jQuery shows only 1 alert.

You can also refer to this link : [re-firing a click event on a link with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762703/re-firing-a-click-event-on-a-link-with-jquery/1763231#1763231)

**Solution**

If you are just looking to open a [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) try this:

```
$("table tr").bind('click',function(e) {
        var elem = $(e.target);
        if(elem.is('a')){
            return;    
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var parent= elem.is('tr') ? elem:elem.parents("tr").eq(0);
        parent.find("a").trigger('click.fb');
    });
```

where `click.fb` is the event that fancybox binds with the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.fancybox').click(function(evt){evt.stopPropagation())});

$('table tr:has[.fancybox]').click(function(evt){
$(this).find('.fancybox').trigger('click')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you're looking for. What you need to do is to call `click()` on the anchor tag in the handler, and make sure you ignore events from the anchor itself. Also, WebKit doesn't support `click()`, so you have to implement it yourself.

Notice from the fiddle below that it properly follows the link target, that is, opens a new window, or loads into the same window. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/5pv5A/3/

```
// Some browsers (WebKit) don't support the click method on links
if (!HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.click) {
    HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.click = function() {
      var target = this.getAttribute('target');
      var href = this.getAttribute('href');
      if (!target) {
          window.location = href;
      } else {
          window.open(href, target);
      }          
    }
}

$("table tr").bind('click',function(e) {
    // This prevents the stack overflow
    if (e.target.tagName == 'A') {
        return;
    }
    // This triggers the default behavior of the anchor
    // unlike calling jQuery trigger('click')
    $(this).find("a").get(0).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My usecase was to trigger a click when a -element was clicked. Checking the type of the target element solves the recursive call problem.

```
$('#table tbody td').click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('td')) {
        $(this).find('input').trigger('click');
    }
});
```