# Issue in conditionally preventing the default action of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an anchor tag: inventoryHome which takes the user to a different page.

If the size of rateMap is greater than 0, I need to show a confirmation pop-up confirming if the user wants to discard the unsaved changes.

The method navigateToInv() is called if the user confirms the discard.

In the code below, though the navigateToInv() method is called & the click event is getting triggered, the page is not navigating to the new page.

```
<li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/inventory" id="inventoryHome"> <spring:message code="inventoryTab" /></a></li>

    $('#inventoryHome').click(function(e) {
            if (Object.size(rateMap) > 0) {

                e.preventDefault();
                showDiscardConfirmationPopUp(navigateToInv, false);
            }
        });

    var navigateToInv = function (){
        rateMap = new Object();
         $('#inventoryHome').trigger('click');
    }

 Object.size = function(obj) {
     var size = 0, key;
     for (key in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
     }
     return size;
 };
```

Not able to identify the issue.

Comment: This seems awfully convoluted.  What if you grabbed the current href from the anchor and did a document.location.href= thatUrl?

Comment: Thanks Steve. Such a simple & straightforward way to achieve it. :)

Comment: Will answer how I achieved the same once I am allowed to answer that is after 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the same as:

```
var navigateToInv = function(){
    document.location.href= $("#inventoryHome").attr('href'); 
} 
$('#inventoryHome').click(function(e) { 
    if (Object.keys(ratePopUpMap).length > 0) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     showDiscardConfirmationPopUp(navigateToInv, false);
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that calling `trigger('click')` on an anchor tag does not cause it to navigate to the page specified by the href value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762703/re-firing-a-click-event-on-a-link-with-jquery/1763231#1763231).

You either have to set `window.location` to the href value, or change the logic so you call `e.preventDefault()` only after the user has chosen not to discard the changes, like this:

```
$('#linkId').click(function(e) {
    if (hasUnsavedChanges() && !confirmDiscard()) {
         e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
$('#inventoryHome').click(function(e) {
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(rateMap) && !confirm("Discard changes?")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand the issue. Incorporating all the comments, I achieved the same as: `var navigateToInv = function(){
 document.location.href= $("#inventoryHome").attr('href');
}  $('#inventoryHome').click(function(e) {
  if (Object.keys(ratePopUpMap).length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
             showDiscardConfirmationPopUp(navigateToInv, false);
  }
 });`

Comment: Object.keys(rateMap) has issues with IE. (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/object-keys-fails-in-ie8) Thats the reason I did not accept the answer.

Comment: @Shikha - The point of the answer is that `trigger()` will not work in your case. I showed `Object.keys()` in the code because you put that in your comment above. Your original code already had a function to test if `rateMap` had any properties, but I think you could use `$.isEmptyObject()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

The issue appears to be that `rateMap` isn't ever changing to be `<= 0`. So even once you call the `click()` method manually, it's still following the chain that disables the default action, which is why it doesn't redirect to the desired page. You should add another state variable that starts out true, so it triggers the prevent default branch, and then is set to false immediately before the manual call of `click()` within `navigateToInv()`.

Comment: rateMap = new Object(); in  navigateToInv() does set it to zero.